# Pytorch NLP sequence length of target in Transformer

Tags: nlp, pytorch, mask, transformer-model

I'm trying to understand the code of Transformer (https://github.com/SamLynnEvans/Transformer).

If seeing the train_model function in "train" script, I wonder why need to use the different sequence length of trg_input from trg:

```
trg_input = trg[:, :-1]
```

In this case, the sequence length of trg_input is "seq_len(trg) - 1".
It means that trg is like:

```
<sos> tok1 tok2 tokn <eos>
```

and trg_input is like:

```
<sos> tok1 tok2 tokn    (no eos token)
```

Please let me know the reason.

Thank you.

The related code is like below:

```
    for i, batch in enumerate(opt.train):
        src = batch.src.transpose(0, 1).to('cuda')
        trg = batch.trg.transpose(0, 1).to('cuda')

        trg_input = trg[:, :-1]
        src_mask, trg_mask = create_masks(src, trg_input, opt)
        preds = model(src, trg_input, src_mask, trg_mask)
        ys = trg[:, 1:].contiguous().view(-1)
        opt.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = F.cross_entropy(preds.view(-1, preds.size(-1)), ys, ignore_index=opt.trg_pad)
        loss.backward()
        opt.optimizer.step()


def create_masks(src, trg, opt):
    
    src_mask = (src != opt.src_pad).unsqueeze(-2)

    if trg is not None:
        trg_mask = (trg != opt.trg_pad).unsqueeze(-2)
        size = trg.size(1) # get seq_len for matrix
        np_mask = nopeak_mask(size, opt)
        if trg.is_cuda:
            np_mask.cuda()
        trg_mask = trg_mask & np_mask
        
    else:
        trg_mask = None
    return src_mask, trg_mask
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the entire aim is to generate the next token based on the tokens we've seen so far. Take a look at the input into the model when we get our predictions. We're not just feeding the source sequence, but also the target sequence *up until our current step*. The model inside `Models.py` looks like:

```
class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, src_vocab, trg_vocab, d_model, N, heads, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(src_vocab, d_model, N, heads, dropout)
        self.decoder = Decoder(trg_vocab, d_model, N, heads, dropout)
        self.out = nn.Linear(d_model, trg_vocab)
    def forward(self, src, trg, src_mask, trg_mask):
        e_outputs = self.encoder(src, src_mask)
        #print("DECODER")
        d_output = self.decoder(trg, e_outputs, src_mask, trg_mask)
        output = self.out(d_output)
        return output
```

So you can see that the `forward` method receives `src` and `trg`, which are each fed into the encoder and decoder. This is a bit easier to grasp if you take a look at the model architecture from [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762):

[image]

The "Outputs (shifted right)" corresponds to `trg[:, :-1]` in the code.